# Event object from onClick event couldn't access one of the props on the element in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

The program logic for the section where I run into trouble is that the function, named handleOperation, for handling state change(this.setState) will be invoked and supplied with two arguments once the corresponding buttons are clicked and the event is triggered, which calls handleOperation function and passed two arguments(obtained from event.currentTarget) to it. However, the console.log prints "submit" for the prop("type") that I intend to grab(It should have returned the value for "type"-either "sesnLength" or "brkLength" in this case)

This is the [link](https://codepen.io/john-huang/full/BaWGywa) to the project I am currently working on.

The following is the code snippet for my class component(parent component) where I supply child component(TimerLengthControl) with "type" property.

```
render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <TimerLengthControl 
              title="Break Length"
              titleID="break-label"
              decrementID="break-decrement"
              incrementID="break-increment"
              spanID="break-length"
              span={this.state.brkLength}
              type="brkLength"
              onClick={this.handleBreakLength}
            />
          <TimerLengthControl 
              title="Session Length"
              titleID="session-label"
              decrementID="session-decrement"
              incrementID="session-increment"
              spanID="session-length"
              span={this.state.sesnLength}
              type="sesnLength"
              onClick={this.handleSessionLength}
            />
          <TimerControl 
            sessionLength={this.state.sesnLength}
            onClick={this.handleReset}
            />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The onClick events are set up here on button elements in my child component(TimerLengthControl) from which the "type" and "value" will be fetched once this event is triggered.

```
const TimerLengthControl=(props)=>(
  <div className="LengthContainer">
    <div className="controlTitle" id={props.titleID}>{props.title}</div>
    <div>
      <button 
        id={props.decrementID} 
        value="-1" 
        type={props.type} 
        onClick={props.onClick}
        >
      <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
      </button>
      <span id={props.spanID}>{props.span}</span>
      <button 
        id={props.incrementID} 
        value="+1" 
        type={props.type}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        >
      <i className="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>  
 )
```

Here are the functions defined for handling the click event and some operations and this is also where I run into trouble. The console.log(**e.currentTarget.type**) prints **"submit"** rather than **sesnLength** or **brkLength**. I want to pass either of these along with **"value"** as arguments to the function "**handleOperation**" to update the parts of the state intended.

```
handleOperation(stateToChange,amount){
  this.setState({[stateToChange]:this.state[stateToChange]+amount})
}
handleBreakLength(e){
console.log(e.currentTarget.type)
const {type, value}=e.currentTarget
this.handleOperation(type,value)
}
handleSessionLength(e){
const {type, value}=e.currentTarget
this.handleOperation(type,value)
}
```

Comment: So is the issue that the event object doesn't have the values you expect? Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have a bit more context around what and where the event object comes from?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I just updated it. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The only valid values for the `type` attribute for HTML `button` elements is `"submit"`, `"button"`, and `"reset"`. This is why you are seeing the console log "submit" always.

## Solution

I suggest converting the `handleBreakLength` and `handleSessionLength` click handlers to curried functions to close over a `type` key for the state updates.

```
handleBreakLength(type) {
  return (e) => {
    console.log(type);
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    this.handleOperation(type, value);
  };
}

handleSessionLength(type) {
  return (e) => {
    console.log(type);
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    this.handleOperation(type, value);
  };
}
```

Remove the `type` prop and close over the "types" you want passed to the handlers.

```
<TimerLengthControl
  title="Break Length"
  titleID="break-label"
  decrementID="break-decrement"
  incrementID="break-increment"
  spanID="break-length"
  span={this.state.brkLength}
  onClick={this.handleBreakLength("brkLength")} // <-- close over type
/>
<TimerLengthControl
  title="Session Length"
  titleID="session-label"
  decrementID="session-decrement"
  incrementID="session-increment"
  spanID="session-length"
  span={this.state.sesnLength("sesnLength")}
  onClick={this.handleSessionLength("sesnLength")} // <-- close over type
/>
```

In `TimerLengthControl` hardcode a `type="button"` attribute so you won't accidentally submit any enclosing `form` elements.

```
<button
  id={props.decrementID}
  value="-1"
  type="button"
  onClick={props.onClick}
>
  <i className="fas fa-arrow-down"></i>
</button>
<span id={props.spanID}>{props.span}</span>
<button
  id={props.incrementID}
  value="+1"
  type="button"
  onClick={props.onClick}
>
  <i className="fas fa-arrow-up"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but there are still some parts where I am still fuzzy. I think I kind of know why it doesn't retrieve the wanted data. The problem is solved also using "event.currentTarget.getAttribute("type")". The type was defined as attribute and the property  "type" in event object which I was trying to fetch is not the same as "type" attribute on the button element. But it begs another question, which is why they differ?

Comment: @JohnHuang Ah, interesting, and unfortunately I don't have an answer for that one, seems peculiar.